# Swift integerForKey: If the specified key does not exist, this method returns 0

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to store an integer in NSUserDefaults that could potentially be 0.  How do I distinguish between an integer that was stored as 0 and a key that does not exist in NSUserDefaults?

According to [the NSUserDefaults docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/integerForKey:) `integerForKey` returns 0 if the key did not exist in NSUserDefaults.  So, my question is: how do I distinguish between a nonexistent key and a key I've stored as 0?

Comment: One approach is to assume the value exists. If it doesn't, 0 is the default, but how is it different than if it exists and is 0? If you need a default value different than 0, use `NSUserDefaults.registerDefaults`, which will give default values to non existing keys, but will not override values of keys that do exist.

Comment: Note that there is a third option: The key exists, but its value is not an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check by using the `objectForKey` method because this method doesn't automatically returns 0 but returns nil, if the key doesn't exist:

```
if let yourInteger = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey"){
    //Key exists
}
```

You could create an extension for your NSUserDefaults to check:

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    func hasKey(key: String) -> Bool {
        return objectForKey(key) != nil
    }
}
```